# RegEx to match several URL patterns with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying to match any of several URL patterns in Javascript.  The patterns are:

- The home page - the `/` without anything after.
- One of three solutions pages. Each `solutions(number)` could be followed by a `/` and any characters after.

  - `/solutions/99043` or `/solutions/99043/blah`
  - `/solutions/60009` or `/solutions/60009/blah`
  - `/solutions/40117` or `/solutions/40117/blah`
- Search: `/search` followed by any characters after, e.g. `?blah`.

The RegEx I tried is as follows:

```
/\/$|\/solutions\/(99043|60009|40117)\/.*|\/search.*/
```

In this function:

```
(function () {
    const urlPath = window.location.pathname;
    if (urlPath.match(/\/$|\/solutions\/(99043|60009|40117)\/.*|\/search.*/)) {
        console.log("urlPath", urlPath);
    }
})()
```

It doesn't work in that everything seems to be matched.  Anyone have any ideas where I went wrong?

Based on a comment, an example of a URL that matches but shouldn't:
`/solutions/`

Comment: Could you provide some test cases where there is unintended behaviour?

Comment: @Bazza I've updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of anchors to assert that start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

Match `/` and optionally match either the part with solutions followed by the 3 numbers or match the search part using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
^\/(?:solutions\/(?:99043|60009|40117)(?:\/.*)?|search\b.*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\/` Match `/`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `solutions\/` Match `solutions/`
  - `(?:99043|60009|40117)` Match 1 of the 3 numbers
  - `(?:\/.*)?` Optionally match `/` and any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `|` Or
  - `search\b.*` Match search followed by a word boundary to not match for example `searchhere`
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hIa0qd/1)

Comment: The `^` start of string causes my RegEx to fail for some reason, but the additional `?:` in the solutions or condition fixes the scenario where `/solutions/` alone was passing.

Comment: The `^` anchors the pattern to the start of the string and `$` to the end. You can remove the anchors in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are extracting the pathname from URL and then performing the matching, I would recommend to use `^\/$` instead of just matching “ends with slash”.

So that would be `^\/$|\/solutions\/(99043|60009|40117)\/.*|\/search.*`

You can test it on regex101.com. I’ve found regulex to be really helpful for visualizing regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the following regular expression:**

```
^\/((solutions(\/(99043|60009|40117)(\/.*)?)?)|search(.*)?)$
```

**Test:**

```js
var regex = /^\/((solutions(\/(99043|60009|40117)?(\/.*)?)?)|search(.*)?)?$/

console.log(1, regex.test('/')) // true

console.log(2, regex.test('/solutions')) // true
console.log(3, regex.test('/solutions/')) // true

console.log(4, regex.test('/solutions/99043')) // true
console.log(5, regex.test('/solutions/99043/')) // true
console.log(6, regex.test('/solutions/99043/anything')) // true

console.log(7, regex.test('/solutions/60009')) // true
console.log(8, regex.test('/solutions/60009/')) // true
console.log(9, regex.test('/solutions/60009/anything')) // true

console.log(10, regex.test('/solutions/40117')) // true
console.log(11, regex.test('/solutions/40117/')) // true
console.log(12, regex.test('/solutions/40117/anything')) // true

console.log(13, regex.test('/solutions/00000')) // false
console.log(14, regex.test('/solutions/00000/')) // false
console.log(15, regex.test('/solutions/00000/anything')) // false

console.log(16, regex.test('/bug')) // false

console.log(17, regex.test('/search?query=javascript')) // true
console.log(18, regex.test('/search/?query=javascript')) // true
```

**So, this regular expression prevents from the following bugs:**

- Prevents testing sub-string rather then a full pathname:

`/bug/solutions/99043` // false

- Prevents testing just a part of solutions numbers:

`/solutions/990430000` // false

`/solutions/000099043` // false

Comment: `/solutions/` cannot be standalone: it has to be followed by either of the three numbers provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
\/(solutions|search)(\/(99043|60009|40117).*|)
```

https://regex101.com/r/nqtB4v/2

Comment: Also matches numbers that start with the given numbers

Comment: Points for the simplest answer, except it doesn't handle the `/` (homepage) scenario.